# Indexing Techniques

Tags: database, indexing, hash, hashtable, b-tree

Given two different indexing techniques, indexing with trees (b+trees) and indexing with hash indexes. Which indexing technique is the best suited for each of the queries below (the the correct index per attribute)?

You can assume the simple case that the B+Tree has a height of more than 4 and that the hash-table does not have any overflows. 
Moreover, the `Person.id` is the primary key of the relation.

[image: queries]

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook/manual with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show what relevant parts you can do & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Hash tables do not support range queries

-You can only access elements by their primary key with a hash table

-Hash indexes are suitable for point lookups (equality queries)

For those reasons, 
the answers should be:

1st query _ age _ `b+ tree`

2nd query _ age _ `b+ tree` _ id _ `hash-index`